# Multiple parameters to Smarty modifier

Tags: php, smarty

Say I have a modifier that looks like this:

```
{$smarty.now|my_modifier:"param1"}
```

But imagine that my_modifier now expects two parameters and not just `"param1"`. How would I pass those?

I want to do something like this:

```
{$smarty.now|my_modifier:"param1","param2"}
```

Comment: two parameters means ? time ?

Comment: I put that modifier as an example. I am talking generally. How to pass two parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifiers.tpl), you simply separate them with a colon ":"

Variable modifiers can be applied to variables, custom functions or strings. To apply a modifier, specify the value followed by a | (pipe) and the modifier name. A modifier may accept additional parameters that affect its behavior. **These parameters follow the modifer name and are separated by a : (colon).** Also, all php-functions can be used as modifiers implicitly (more below) and modifiers can be combined. .

So I would assume

`{$smarty.now|my_modifier:"param1":"param2"}`

Comment: How can I pass param2  if it is a variable?